# Merge sort mxn matrix

Tags: matrices, mergesort

The question is as follows:

[image]

I am new to this, and I do not understand how to apply divide and conquer to a matrix, the algorithm that I have come up with is as follows (I am not sure if I am correct)

I thought I can divide the matrix into a matrices of 3 x 3 and 2 x 3 first. Then I will apply sorting of rows over column individually on both the matrices. Finally I will copy the second matrix sorting result over to the first sorted matrix. However, my problem is how do I sort the matrix first in to some order so that my division will yield a correct partition else what happens is, post copy I have to again sort (Which I thought is probably wrong)

Comment: Please transcribe the text in your image -- images are inaccessible to search engines and people with visual difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, "sort the rows of the matrix, with respect to their columns" means that you're supposed to sort the rows lexicographically. That is, the row
$$a_1\ a_2\ \ldots\ a_n$$
comes before
$$b_1\ b_2\ \ldots\ b_n$$
if and only if there's some $i$ such that $a_j=b_j$ for $j<i$ and $a_i<b_i$.

As far as the divide and conquer goes, it doesn't matter that it's a two-dimensional matrix. You're trying to sort a collection of "things" according to some ordering on "things". These "things" happen to be the rows of some array but that doesn't make any difference to the algorithm.

Comment: can you please explain how to apply "if and only if there's some i such that aj=bj for j<i and ai<bi" to the given matrix, I did not quite understand it. Thanks

Comment: Check each possible $i$ in turn.

Comment: But we have to apply merge sort right, that means we will have to divide the matrix into sub matrices and then finally merge them back right

Comment: Yes but just think of it as a one-dimensional array, where each entry of the array is a thing called a row. Basically, the answer is "It's just standard merge sort except for the coding."

Comment: And what impact will it have on time complexity?

Comment: @shakeelosmani Write down the algorithm. It’s only a small modification to standard merge sort, so the derivation of the time complexity should also only be a small modification to standard merge sort.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I got all that. Just stuck at part c question any idea?

Comment: I suggest you think about it a little more. Note that ordinary merge sort makes precisely the assumption that comparisons take time $\Theta(1)$.